# Calling removeFromSuperview on subview in UICollectionViewCell does not work on first load, only when cell is reused

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell with a number of subviews. One of the subviews I want to remove altogether so the adjacent subview can expand to fill that space via constraints.

This constraint configuration set up within the prototype cell in storyboard, and the subview is already in place in the prototype, ready to be removed after the cell has been instantiated.

My `UICollectionViewCell` subclass has a setter that does this:

```
- (void)setThing:(NSString *)aThing
{
     if (!aThing)
     {
          [self.thingContainerView removeFromSuperview];
          return;
     }
     // proceed if aThing exists
```

And when the cell is setup:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"mycellid" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.aThing = nil; //this should trigger removal of one of the cell's subviews
    return cell;
}
```

The problem is **when the `UICollectionViewCell` is first loaded, the subview has not been removed.**  Once I've scrolled the cell offscreen and returned to it, the subview has been removed as expected.  So I'm assuming there's some sort of issue with the cell not being fully laid out when I'm setting the property the first time around.

How to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the view has been laid out at that point so the subview cannot be removed. Try removing it in a different method such as;

```
- (void) didMoveToSuperview
{
    if (!self.aThing)
    {
         [self.thingContainerView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This will be overridden in your collection view cell.

There might be a more appropriate method to call this in but this should work.

Comment: I found an alternate method as well, which is overriding `layoutSubviews`, although it appears to be called multiple times.

Comment: I discovered this unfortunately this has the side effect of the subview being gone when the cell eventually gets reused.  Adding it back of course means I need to re-add all of its constraints. I wish I could get rid of cell reuse altogether.

Comment: You could try setting cell.hidden = YES and then manipulating the height/width constraint of the cell. Autolayout should then adjust the other views around it and then when you want the cell back, just revert the height/width constraint and set cell.hidden = NO;